# Does $Z(t)$ have stationary increments?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let be $$Z(t)= \int_t^{t+1}B(s)\,ds-B(t)$$ a process where $\{B(t), t \ge0\}$ be a standard Brownian Motion. I have to show that $Z(t)$ has stationary increments.

$\textbf{My very poor ideas: }$

I have to prove that $Z(t+h)-Z(t) \sim Z(h)-Z(0)$ for all $h \ge 0$.

I see that $Z(0) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac13)$ but I don't know if this let me far away because If i extend $Z(t+h)-Z(t)$, it looks like very complicate.

So maybe can I prove that $\int_t^{t+1}B(s)\,ds$ is indipendent from $B(t)$? Is it helpful?

Thank you for any hint.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^t B(s)\ \mathsf ds$ is a Gaussian process with zero mean and variance $\frac13 t^3$.

Comment: Yes, i prove it to prove that $\int_0^1 B(s)ds \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. How can I use it to $\int_t^{t+1}B(s)ds$?

Comment: No, $$\mathsf{Var}\left(\int_0^1 B(s)\ \mathsf ds\right) = \frac13. $$

Comment: Yes sorry. I wrote it correct in the text.